# Why do we usually use "a piece of paper" instead of just "a paper"?

Tags: phrases

When people refer to a sheet of paper, usually one would say "a piece of paper" instead simply "a paper".

For example, "I am writing on a piece of paper" and not "I am writing on a paper".

Why is this?

Comment: Because "paper", without further qualification, is too ambiguous.

Comment: In that particular context, "writing on paper" is far more common than either according to [NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=writing+on+paper%2Cwriting+on+a+*%2Cwriting+on+a+paper&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3).

Comment: Writing on a paper suggests writing on a newspaper.  Writing on paper contrasts, today, with writing on a computer.

Comment: *Paper* is non-count in that context. So if you want some of it, you need to specify some unit of measure - e.g. piece, stack, sheet, etc.

Comment: Paper is uncountable (like sugar, sand and water). So you ask for *some* paper, even when you want (and are given) a single sheet.

Comment: 'A' paper is an article which is read or presented, usually to one's peers, as a stated piece of research. 'He delivered a paper on genetics to the Royal Society'.

Comment: See ELL's  [I gave him a paper to read](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/85783/i-gave-him-a-paper-to-read) and also ELL's  [What is this called in English? paper / sheets/ blank page (picture is attached)](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/72809/what-is-this-called-in-english-paper-sheets-blank-page-picture-is-attached)

Comment: See also ELL's [A piece of paper and not 'a paper'](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/73727/a-piece-of-paper-and-not-a-paper)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a synopsis.

> I stopped for a *paper* (newspaper)
>
> The instructor wanted a *paper* on it done by Friday (academic paper)

If you fall in bad company

> Hand me a *paper* (a paper for rolling some sort of cigarette)
>
> Is there any *paper* on him? (arrest warrants, etc.)

There are many ways a *paper* might mean something specific in English [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/paper). Some of them are not much used anymore, such as the *paper* in which one would place the powder and projectile for a  muzzle loading rifle cartridge. That *paper* can be used to mean so many things requires careful use at times. So, "piece of paper" or "sheet of paper" is used for some paper to write on.
If someone asks me for a *paper* I will need to ask what is meant.